# Вывод результата работы скрипта на экран

Tags: python-3.x, вывод, экран

Друзья, подскажите, как вывести результат работы скрипта Python на экран в Windows?
К примеру, есть скрипт, который парсит нужные данные.
Не знаю, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы на рабочем столе был файл, по которому кликаешь и он тебе выводит результат парсинга прямо на рабочий стол системным сообщением(Не обязательно системным).
Или такое можно решить, только перекомпилировав .py в .exe?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, Вам поможет `Windows API`.

***На примере*** `MessageBox`***:***

```
import ctypes


def main() -> None:
    MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW
    MessageBox(None, 'Hello', 'Window title', 0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***Результат*** *(Windows 10):*

[image: Пример MessageBox]

***UPD:***

Для того чтобы скрыть окно консоли, можно изменить расширение файла на `pyw`.

Comment: Интересный вариант.
Можно ли с помощью объекта MessageBox обернуть две функции?
К примеру, так MessageBox((get_page(get_html(url))))

И все равно придётся вручную запускать скрипт, чтобы увидеть результат.

Comment: `MessageBox` принимает 4 аргумента. Вам важны 2-4. Это текст сообщения, заголовок окна и "магическое число" (обозначающее тип окна) соответственно. Подставлять значения, используя переменные или результат, возвращенный функцией, никто не запрещает. Насчёт ручного запуска скрипта - я не понял, что Вы имеете в виду, поясните подробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: Обернув вызовы своих функций, выводит пустое окно.
Имею ввиду, иметь файл на рабочем столе, кликнув по которому, выводятся результаты из скрипта.

Именно кликнув, а не запускать через консоль или редактор кода.
В Линуксе есть крон, который по времени выводит действие.
Мне нужно в винде такое, но не по времени, а по моему клику.

Comment: Пример, который Вы привели в первом комментарии, не работает, потому что вместо 4-х аргументов Вы передали 1. А насчёт запуска, я всё ещё не могу Вас понять. Кликнув 2 раза по скрипту, он запускается. Никто не мешает Вам запускать его по-другому, через различные планировщики и т. п. Но это уже совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: MessageBox(None, get_page(get_html(url)), 'Window title', 0)
Про запуск я имел ввиду так.
Окно запускается, но оно пустое без результатов.
Кликнув в 2 клика, я лишь запущу редактор кода .py файла.
А нужно, чтобы после двух кликов вылезало сообщение с результатом.
БЕЗ запуска редактора.

Comment: @Proton А что Вам возвращает функция? Вы можете быть уверены, что это строка? Насчёт запуска - Вы можете изменить программу, которая по умолчанию открывает Ваш скрипт. `ПКМ -> Открыть с помощью -> Выбрать другое приложение -> Python`. А чтобы не было окна консоли, измените расширение файла на `pyw`.